# Is it informal to omit the word "that" when it's optional?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, that

I know there have been many questions about omitting "that" or not, but none of them addressed *formality*. I am writing a thesis in Romania and my supervisor gave me some feedback in which, among other things, he added "that" in many places where it was omitted. I didn't understand why so I asked him, and he said it's informal to omit "that", and that a thesis shouldn't be in such informal language. I was a bit perplexed because I have never heard such a thing. I looked online and couldn't find any source confirming his point. In my view, his inclination to always make "that" explicit is a result of his being a native speaker of Romanian, which doesn't have the option of omitting the equivalent word, but I could be wrong. I am not a native English speaker either so I cannot settle the dispute. Does anybody have information on this? Is it really informal to omit "that"? I would be particularly interested in answers that either cite sources or are the opinion of native speakers.

For reference, the first sentence he corrected was:

> However, to dismiss the broader idea that we must respect certain criteria in order to be entitled to claim [that] our statements are meaningful is also an equally absurd position.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether he's right or not. He's your thesis advisor. Why not write in Rumanian?

Comment: As a native English speaker, I do not believe it is a question of formality, The particular sentence you gave as an example does read a little better, more clearly with "that". But I don't think formal or informal has anything to do with it.

Comment: @JohnLawler the master's program is in English and the thesis must therefore be written in English. Besides, I am not a native speaker of Romanian. In any case, he's not a rigid authoritarian advisor, he's a reasonable and rational person who responds to arguments, so I don't have to blindly do whatever he says.

Comment: With a less exacting sentence: 'This proves the volcano, which has always been known to be far from extinct, is on the verge of eruption.' No; it sounds awkward, mixing registers; I'd leave the 'that' here. Also, with more complicated sentences, as @Isabel goes on to say, clarity / ease of parsing is added. Omitting 'that' in such cases violates a Gricean maxim.

Comment: To me, the inclusion or exclusion of the second *that* in the sentence is much less a problem than the structure of the sentence as a whole. By the time you get to *meaningful*, you tend to lose track of the meaning of the sentence when reading what follows it. It would be better to move the final words to the start: *However, **it is also an equally absurd position** to dismiss the broader idea that …*

Comment: @JasonBassford I see, it makes sense. When you've read a sentence literally more than a hundred times (this sentence is in my abstract so you can imagine I've read it a lot), it's hard to _not_ understand it. It seems clear and easy to me. But indeed it's a long sentence and I understand that for somebody reading it for the first time, it may be hard to parse, so I'll rephrase it. Thanks for the feedback :)